# How much is too much for a browser loading content onScroll?

Tags: javascript, ajax, testing, optimization, browser

Since sites like [The Official Google Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com.es/), [Twitter](https://twitter.com/#lolz) and [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) are loading content via ajax each time the user scrolls down, I want to know how much is too much? which is the best way for testing this on every browser?

Thanks!

Comment: on the google blog, after 20 page downs, memory consumption of the browser (IE9) got to 900MB (!!!!). i think people with low end computers will have a very big problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *[Asking "what are the limits" is like asking "how big is a glass of water"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220530/what-are-the-limits-to-pushing-javascript-performance/10220623#comment13129588_10220623)*
>
> -RobG.

You can't and will never have a real limit. If you insist, the limits are:

- The capability of the user's browser
- The user's hardware
- The user's patience to an ever increasingly laggy UI caused by heap and processing starvation.